# `ssh-add <key>` doesn't add my key to the agent

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I start a new shell (new terminal window), then here are all the commands I run:

```
user@host :~ $ eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
Agent pid 1413341
user@host :~ $ ssh-add -vvv ~/.ssh/keys/<mykey>
Enter passphrase for /home/mate/.ssh/keys/<mykey>: 
user@host :~ $ ssh-add -l
The agent has no identities.
```

`ssh-add` doesn't return any output, but after verification, returns an error code of `1` (tried `ssh-add ...` again then `echo $?`). However, it really doesn't print any output on stderr.

The env vars $SSH_AGENT_PID and $SSH_AUTH_SOCK are correctly set after the `eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"` command.

PS: Also tried the full operation with `eval "$(ssh-agent)"` instead, to no avail.

PS: Unless I missed something, all questions on stackoverflow, superuser, and unix.stackexchange are dealing with another specific case, such as running `ssh-add` alone (and thus only taking standard key locations into account) or people who haven't started the agent correctly etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, turns out it was apparently due to a needed (very recent) package update, cause it works again now after a system update and a reboot.

Out of all packages updated matched against dependencies of `openssh`, the culprit seems to be `tzdata`. So check pending package updates on your system.

PS: Take this with a grain of salt cause there are many entangled dependencies of which I'm not sure how all of this works under the hood (`libcap` `libcap-ng`, `libgcrypt` `libxcrypt`, etc...).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a new user that was created using `adduser`. It turns out this new user was created without a `config` file in the `.ssh` folder.

I created such a file with the line

```
AddKeysToAgent yes
```

That seems to have solved my problem. However security is a delicate problem and SSH has many configurations, and it's possible that other points will need fine tuning, like `SSH_ASKPASS`, etc.